# Chef recipe gives error as undefined method 'split'

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, chef, ruby, chef-solo

Hi I am using below in code in my chef recipe and it works fine with all the other existing servers however it doesn't work well with my new server.

```
user_array = node
node['user']['user_array_node_attr'].split("/").each do |hash_key|
  user_array = user_array.send(:[], hash_key)
end
```

And gives error as

`FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 0):

`node['user']['user_array_node_attr']` is not defined, but `node['user']` is. Check your attribute specification to make sure this has a value. Where does this value come from?

If it comes from another recipe, you might be in a situation where your run_list assumes this has a value before the recipe that defines it runs.  This scenario can happen over time as cookbooks change --  a prior version sets the attribute properly and gets replaced, so existing nodes work fine but new nodes fail.

Comment: I guess it's the same as what you described above. Will it help to bring the whole vendor cookbooks folder to new repository? I mean I am using berkshelf chef and vendoring all the cookbooks in vendor/cookbooks folder.

Comment: That won't help -- the issue is a logical one. Cookbook A a time set that value, cookbook B was written to read it. A is changed to no longer write it but the value persists on existing nodes. Everything works until a new node is added where the value isn't set.  You have to review your cookbooks / roles / environments and determine what is supposed to set that attribute.